# How do I install Xcode from a dmg file?

Tags: macos, xcode

I just downloaded Xcode from Apple's website.

I got the `dmg` file named `xcode_432_lion.dmg`. After mounting `xcode_432_lion.dmg`, when I open that disk, it's just showing me a file named Xcode. When I click on Xcode, it simply starts the application.

Why isn't it installing Xcode? I want to install Xcode and all other tools so that I can also get them from a terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just drag the `Xcode.app` to `/Applications` and start it from there.

Xcode used to be installed to `/Developer`, but not anymore. It's a self-contained application package now.

According to [Apple's release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html),

> the simplification afforded by repackaging Xcode 4.3 as a single app bundle eliminates the need for the /Developer directory containing prior versions of Xcode. As a result, the Install Xcode application and the uninstall-devtools command line script are also no longer needed.

Furthermore, the Xcode command line tools are …

> not bundled with Xcode 4.3 by default. Instead, they can be installed optionally using the Components tab of the Downloads preferences panel as shown in Figure 3.

So open Xcode.app, then click *Xcode » Preferences*, or press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Expanding on this:  the App Store can't use installers, it can only copy application bundles to `/Applications`.  So if you want to install manually, you copy the application bundle yourself; there is no installer to run any more, nor does the short-lived `Install Xcode.app` exist any more.

Comment: then how to use commands thats are being installed with xcode?

Comment: where to find this Download Preferences Panel?

Comment: @coure2011 Uhm. Isn't it in Xcode's preferences?